# Failed to CREATE_FILE in hdfs

Tags: hdfs, hdp

I have a java program that try to write a file into hdfs, but i get this error message:

```
Failed to CREATE_FILE /data/xxx because DFSClient_attempt_1552693040212_69961_m_000000_0_1265362509_1 is already the current lease holder.
```

Comment: can you try remove the file and let spark re-create it?

Comment: also can you provide your python/spark script so we can better understand why there is the error?

Comment: yes i removed the file and re-run my job. it's a simple write

Comment: lease errors are usually related to concurrency issues, could you ensure that there is other (may be ghost) process accessing the same resources in your hdfs cluster ?